# Woocommerce, дочерняя тема

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

В дочерней теме пытаюсь переопределить хук, который используется в основной теме:
**funcitons.php - основная тема**

```
function thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title($category) {
    echo '<div class="category-overlay">';
    echo '<h6 class="category-title">'.$category->name.'</h6>';
    echo '<div class="category-overlay-separator"></div>';
    echo '<div class="category-count">'.sprintf(esc_html(_n('%s item', '%s items', $category->count, 'thegem')), $category->count).'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10 );
```

**functions.php - дочерняя тема**

```
function thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title1($category) {
    echo '<div class="category-overlay">';
    echo '<h6 class="category-title">'.$category->name.' test</h6>';
    echo '</div>';
}
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title1', 10 );
```

но срабатывают два хука.
Как переопределить хук из основной темы, чтобы он не выводился?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала подключается код плагинов, потом functions.php в дочерней теме, потом в основной - так устроен WordPress. На момент исполнения вашей строки

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10 );
```

функция `thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title` не прикреплена к хуку, поэтому никакого эффекта она не имеет. Как результат - выполняются обе функции, приведенные в вопросе.

В то же время `remove_action` в дочерней теме срабатывает, потому что исполняется после подключения плагина WooCommerce, который и объявляет свою функцию для хука.

Ваш код в дочерней теме должен выглядеть так:

```
function thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title1( $category ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10 );

    echo '<div class="category-overlay">';
    echo '<h6 class="category-title">' . $category->name . ' test</h6>';
    echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title1', 0 );
```

Обратите внимание на приоритет `0` в `add_action` (может быть любым меньше 10). Вы запускаете свою функцию `...title1` по событию `woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title` раньше функции из родительской темы, и прямо внутри своей функции отменяете родительскую.

Comment: а если fuctions.php сначала срабатывает в дочерней теме, подскажите, как же всё таки удаляется ещё не подключённый хук в основной теме с помощью remove_action внутри функции thegem_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title1 ?

Comment: Вы путаете выполнение основного кода (add_, remove_) и кода по хукам. Т.е. сначала плагины, потом дочерняя, потом родительсткая. На этом этапе никаких вызвовов хуков не происходит, они лишь заносятся в глобальный массив хуков WordPress (обе функции там - ...title и title1). Потом WP начинает выводить шапку сайта, строить страницу сверху вниз. В какой-то момент доходит до вызова хука `woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title` - и вот тут срабатывает ваша функция и "устраняет конкурента" - т.е. выкидывает ...title из глобального массива хуков WP.

Comment: После выполнения каждой из функций в глобальном массиве хуков WP смотрит - осталось ли там еще что? А ваша функция уже "устранила конкурента". И WP завершает выполнение этого хука.